# Unable to catching multiple table rows with JSTL forEach in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

The goal: adding multiple table rows dynamically based on user inputs and catch the data through controller.

What I have so far(all simplified):

POJO:

```
public class Item(){
    String price; 
    String weight; 

    getters and setters...
}

public class ItemForm(){
    List<Item> items;

    getter and setter...
}
```

JSP:

```
<form:form action="/create" method="POST" modelAttribute="itemForm">
 <table>
  <tr>
      <td><input type='text' name='price'/></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='weight'/></td>
  </tr>
 </table>

 <c:forEach items="${itemForm.items}" var="item" varStatus="status">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">${status.count}</td>
        <td><input name="items[${status.index}].price" value="${item.price}" /></td>
        <td><input name="items[${status.index}].weight" value="${item.weight}" /></td>
    </tr>
 </c:forEach>
</form:form>
```

Controller:

```
private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveMultipleRows(@ModelAttribute("itemForm") ItemForm itemForm) {

        items = itemForm.getItems();
        if(items != null && items.size() > 0){
            System.out.println("The list is not null!");
        }
        System.out.println("didn't get into the if statement");
        return null;
}
```

I skipped the `Javascript` on adding table rows, if you think that have anything to do with this question, I will update my post and put the `Javascript` code.

The idea is to create a `ItemForm` class that contains a list of `Item` object, and in the JSP using JSTL `c:foreach` to save all the data from users to the list. And in my controller, if the list is not empty, I simply want to print out a message so that I know the list is not empty. But now if I run the program, it prints out "didn't get into the if statement".

So the problem I am currently having is the list is empty, that means I am not able to save the user input data to the list. Can anyone help me and let me know where I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the corrected code 
since you have item in scope you can directly access the props of Item,You dont need to explicitly declare the index

```
 <input name="${item.price}" value="${item.price}" />
    <input name ="${item.weight}" value="${item.weight}" />
```

Comment: this should salve the issue <input name="price" value="${item.price}" />
    <input name ="weight" value="${item.weight}" />